# NPM audit not finding vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-audit, npm-ci

I have a CI service that runs `npm audit` on every build and notifies if there are high-risk vulnerabilities. The strange thing is when CI reports high vulnerabilities when I run `npm audit` locally, it says `found 0 vulnerabilities`. It will find the issue in a few days...

For example, the CI reports about: [`CVE-2020-7774: The npm package y18n before versions 3.2.2, 4.0.1, and 5.0.5 is vulnerable to Prototype Pollution.`](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1654)

But on local dev env:
[image: no issues]

Both CI and local use Node `15.12.0` and npm `7.6.3`.

Why is `npm audit` not finding the latest issues? Is there any way to force update it or something?

`npm --verbose audit` output:

[image]

Comment: You can run `npm --verbose audit` to see the request that gets made - is there anything between you and the registry that might be caching that?

Comment: The request looks normal to me. I don't have something that would cache that... Added the verbose output to the question

Comment: You could try e.g. `curl -vd "$(cat package-lock.json)" https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits` to see if there's anything suspicious in there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Actually it also says no vulnerabilities... I'm not sure why the CI sees different issues...

Comment: The local code is the same as the code in the CI, of course...

Comment: We have a similar issue where CI reports medium risk CVEs but `npm audit --audit-level=moderate` does not. Is there a way to get npm audit to display all CVEs?